# Secondary C Terminal on Furnace Circuit Board?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I was trying to install an Ecobee thermostat, and there was no C wire installed. When I went to install the power extender kit, I saw the standard C wire terminal was broken out of the black plastic casing, and I couldn't attach the C wire. There appears to be a secondary C terminal that is a different style with a plastic plug plugged into it, and then the wire is spliced and connected to the wire heading to the AC unit. Can I add a second wire to this plastic plug, is this a secondary C terminal that should work fine? I attached a pic.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo that shows the main terminal block square-on?

Comment: I added the pics I have on my phone - I am at work now, and can take better pics when I home tonight if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks good to me, the second "C" terminal connects to the chassis in the background of the photo so it most likely is equivalent to the screw-down terminal.

fitting a crimp-on fork lug to the wire would be another alternative if you really want to connect to the screw-down terminal.

Comment: Just an update, I took off the wire nut, added the common wire from the Ecobee power extender kit, added a new wire nut that can handle four wires, and things are working perfect. Thanks again!